# Hide a User control and remove the space

Tags: user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a panel and it is embedded to the default page. And within the panel I have controls and text. My question is how to hide the panel and remove its space when it is rendered on the default page.

Comment: You do not define what language you're programming in. Please add more info for proper help.

Comment: I am programming in vb.net.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Add a tag for VB if you can. That way it may be picked up by the right person. Sorry, can't help you in VB.Net.